# Unknown system variable 'ROWCOUNT'

Tags: sql

I need to insert the records that aren't existing in the table companies.

I'm using the `@@ROWCOUNT` method to check if it exists.

```
UPDATE companies SET `name`='<string>' WHERE `name`='<string>';
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  INSERT INTO companies(`name`, temp) VALUES('<string>', 1);
```

This is what I do ^
And just keeping this error: `Unknown system variable 'ROWCOUNT'`

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is SQL Server syntax. Looks like you are using MySQL. https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: The code shown is not valid (standard) "SQL" - which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks. Stupid, I didn't thought about the `ON DUPLICATE`. Can you set is as answer, so I can resolve this question ^^